Error al compilar: E2597(SystemPath)\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lz
Estoy tratando de re-compilar un programa con Delphi 12 para un target linux64, específicamente Ubuntu 24.04.X LTS después de habilitar skia en el proyecto, pero obtengo este error:
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\23.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lz [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001).

Pensando que algo andaba mal en el caché, reimporté el SDK, pero aún así, sigue fallando.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es instalar el paquete zlib1g-dev en el sistema. Para ello, lanzar el siguiente comando en la terminal:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev

Hay algunas otras bibliotecas que son usualmente requeridas, para asegurarnos de tenerlas instaladas todas (las que tengo identificadas hasta la fecha), se puede usar el siguiente comando:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install joe wget p7zip-full curl build-essential zlib1g-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev

Después de la instalación, es necesario reiniciar el PAServer. (viniendo de Windows, ¿por qué no reiniciar todo el equipo? jejeje)
Después es necesario ir al SDK manager en el IDE de Delphi y dentro de "Linux 64-Bit", actualizar presionando el botón "Update Local File Cache", que está debajo de la lista de rutas remotas en Propiedades.
Todo el proceso está documentado en la docWiki: Linux application development
